# Multiple controls with the same ID '_AccordionExtender' were found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have this incredible problem, with ASP Accordion Control. I am trying to dynamically create multiple accordions on the same WebForm ASP Page. this is an example code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
{
    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
    accordion.ID = customerName + "_Accordion";
    accordion.Panes.Add(accordionPane); // accordionPane: Other dynamically created AccordionPane Control

    this.Panel.Controls.Add(accordion); // Panel: An asp Panel Control in the page
}
```

When I load the page on browser I get this error:

"Multiple controls with the same ID '_AccordionExtender' were found."

I suspect that accordion control add automatically an AccordionExtender on the page, but I extremely need the create those accordion dynamically on the code behind.
Why this error does not appear if I add accordions declaratively in the aspx page?
There is a solution for this problem?
Thanks to all!

Comment: Not sure why you would want to create 12 accordion controls one after the other... if possible forget the asp.net accordion and use the jQuery one.

Comment: Hi thank you for your interest! but this is an exeple code to generate the error! suppose that you want to create only two accordions on the same page! bye

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
{
    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
    accordion.ID = customerName + "_Accordion" + i.toString();
    accordion.Panes.Add(accordionPane); // accordionPane: Other dynamically created AccordionPane Control

    this.Panel.Controls.Add(accordion); // Panel: An asp Panel Control in the page
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is not the accordion id, but is the id of the automatically created AccordionExtender associated to the accordions!

Comment: @Anloboz
Hi, did you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: I used jquery, sorry